# unable to add attachment to sharepoint list using ThyBAG api

Tags: php, drupal-7, sharepoint-online

Environment: Linux
Backend: Drupal/PHP.
Sharepoint API in use: https://github.com/thybag/PHP-SharePoint-Lists-API/

I have successfully established a connection with sharepoint using WSDL file. I am able to insert, delete and update the lists using the above API. But I am not able to add a attachment to the list item. I tried using the API function (addAttachment), but it is throwing the following error-

> "Caught exception: Error (soap:Server) Exception of type
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was
>   thrown.,more=Detailed: The security validation for this page is
>   invalid. Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try
>   your operation again."

Please let me know if anybody facing the same issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for the above problem. The issue lies in this file

> PHPSharePointListsAPI/src/Thybag/Auth/SharePointOnlineAuth.php on line 22

Just replace line 22 with the below code :-

> $headers = array('SOAPAction: "' . $action . '"');

Hope that helps if anyone's stuck with it since ages.. :P